# Express version missing Debug-> exceptions menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

I use. VS 2013 Express
When debugging, I need to stop automatically on exceptions.
try to follow this. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx#AddExceptionsCommand
It says I need to add Exceptions command to the Debug menu

1. On the Tools menu, click Customize.
2. The Customize dialog box appears.
3. Click the Commands tab and, in the Menu bar list, click Debug.
4. Click Add Command.
5. In Categories in the Add Command dialog box, click Debug.
6. In Commands, click Exceptions and then click OK.

But in stage 6, in Commands there is no Exeptions[image]

Also I tried to remove Enable just my code, And it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Just a FYI  ---

Im am using VS Express 2010 (VB) and didn't see the debug exceptions.
Based on the screen shot above I just pushed  CRLT-ALT-E and it opened.. (!)

Its a bit unclear to me, if VB 2010 Express has this option or not, or how to unhide it, but the key click combo opened it.

I was then able to turn off the option I needed 
In my case the "PInvokeStackImbalance"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXiOy.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Another user has reported the missing 'exceptions' on the 'debug' menu to Microsoft and actually got an acknowlegement from Microsoft (though not from the product team and not confirmation that it is a bug).

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/882780/exceptions-comman-missing-in-vs-2013-express-for-web

For what it's worth, you can add your vote to this report at that site; I'm experiencing this problem and I have done so too.

Here's a potential work-around:  the 'exceptions' *is* present in the Visual Studio Express for Desktop.  And you can install that edition side-by-side with Web edition.  If you can figure out a way to invoke your project executable from the debugger in the Desktop edition, you'd have control over exceptions there.

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions menu isn't shown in Visual Studio Web Developer Express. It is only shown in Visual C# Express.

You can however break on all exceptions. You can try to turn off `"Just My Code"` debugging, which will catch exceptions thrown in CLR code and linked libraries.

To do this, open `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General`, and uncheck `"Just My Code"` (or Enable Just My Code).

if it doesn't work try

```
Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions - check "when thrown"
```

[image]

if you don't see exceptions try to change your settings following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1z20s6z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) guide

Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc(v=vs.90).aspx) for documentation.

**update**

if it still not working try this

```
Tools menu >> Import and Export Settings >> Reset all settings. Then choose C# Development Environment.
```

Comment: It didn't work. Still does't break on exception. I use 2013 express for web I call WebApi functions from Javascript

Comment: are you sure? Is that option checked?

Comment: try this one Debug -> Exceptions -> CLR - check "when thrown".

Comment: The problem is that I don't have Debug -> Exceptions, since it is Express edition(As the title of this question says)

Comment: I add imamge that shows I unchecked Enable just my code.

Comment: lookat my image in the answer. Did you have that exception menu?

Comment: I have update my answer with image and new link to add that option

Comment: Which settings should I import? I tried Expert settings, and it doesn't show the Debug /Excptions yet

Comment: Are you using the Visual Basic IDE?

Comment: I've updated with a new one solution.. try that and let me know

Answer (score -1):

Many of the customization and integration features for Visual Studio's IDE are not available in the free Express editions, but you should be able to get to the Exceptions menu easily enough without using them.

Press F5 to start debugging, then select Debug / Exceptions... Turn on the check box for "C++ Exceptions" "Thrown". Hit "OK"

Comment: Problem is I dont have Debug/Exceptoion

Comment: Which Visual Studio Express are you using exactly?

Comment: Don't use Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop. Use Visual Studio Community if you can't afford Pro.